# How to update multi columns in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have DF has 5 columns. 3 columns are character type, and other are numeric type. I wanted to update missing values of character type columns are "missing".

I have written update statement like below, but it's not working.

```
df.select_dtypes(include='object') = df.select_dtypes(include='object').apply(lambda x: x.fillna('missing'))
```

It's working only when i specify column names.

```
df[['Manufacturer','Model','Type']] = df.select_dtypes(include='object').apply(lambda x: x.fillna('missing'))
```

Could you please tell me how i can correct my first update statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `df.select_dtypes(include='object')` return new `DataFrame`, so cannot assign like in first answer, possible solution is use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) (working inplace), also `apply` here is not necessary.

```
print (df)
  Manufacturer Model Type  a    c
0            a     g  NaN  4  NaN
1          NaN   NaN   aa  4  8.0

df.update(df.select_dtypes(include='object').fillna('missing'))
print (df)
  Manufacturer    Model     Type  a    c
0            a        g  missing  4  NaN
1      missing  missing       aa  4  8.0
```

Or get columns names with `string`s like:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna('missing')
print (df)
```